# Want to populate data from two array one at a time using same TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very New in iOS app development so need a little support!!
I have used a TableView in **objectiveC** to make a drop down list to display name of Countries which has been successfully made but now i want the same tableView to be used with different list of states because i am having two NSMutable array one for "**countryList**" and other for "**stateList**"
is it possible for me to use the same tableView but display stateList data.

```
NSMutableArray *countryArray;
NSMutableArray *stateArray;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return countryArray.count ;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return 25;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    static NSString *idenfier = @"countryList";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idenfier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = [countryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.registerCountry.text = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
    // self.countryView.hidden = YES;

    self.countryView.frame = CGRectMake(self.countryView.frame.origin.x, self.countryView.frame.origin.y, self.countryView.frame.size.width, 0);

    if([_registerCountry.text isEqual:@""]){
        [_dropDownState setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else{
        [_dropDownState setEnabled:YES];

    }

}

- (IBAction)dropDownCountry:(id)sender {
    self.countryView.hidden = NO;

    if (self.countryView.frame.size.height != 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.countryView.frame = CGRectMake(self.countryView.frame.origin.x, self.countryView.frame.origin.y, self.countryView.frame.size.width, 0);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // self.dropDownImageView.highlighted = NO;
        }];
    }
    else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.countryView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 404, 302, 100);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // self.dropDownImageView.highlighted = YES;
        }];
    }

}

- (IBAction)dropDownState:(id)sender {
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details by copy-pasting your code here

Comment: It is definitely possible. Post some code as Alexander notes, or post your data source.

Comment: how u want to show country and state list?Means on which action it would be change?Can u provide image of that..

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return stateList.count
     //OR
     return countryList.count
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Load cell with the array[indexPath.row] you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your TableViewController define the enums

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ListViewType)
{
    CountryList,
    StateList
};

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) ListViewType listViewType;

@end


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    switch (self.listViewType)
    {
        case CountryList:
            //Load countryList array
            break;

        case StateList:
            //load stateList array
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

While present view controller set the type of list to be loaded

```
    TableViewController * tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
    tableViewController.listViewType = CountryList; //Set depends on the need (CountryList/ StateList)
    tableViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    tableViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:tableViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible just make isCountry `BOOL` type and check in table view delegate & datasource. and whenver you wants to change tableView values just change value of `isCountry` and `reload` you `tableView`.

Answer (score 0):

***Yes***, Just take one `BOOL` variable to Differentiate between **countryList** and **stateList**  drop down.

Take `BOOL isCountyDropDownClick;`

When any one option click set `BOOL` accordingly and `Reload TableView`.

Like, If Clicked for **countryList** than Set `BOOL` to `YES` and `Reload table` else set `BOOL` to `NO`.

In `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Use Data source array according to `BOOL` Value.

For Example,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (isCountyDropDownClick)
    {

       return  CountryListArray.count;

    }
    else{

       return  StateListArray.count;

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (isCountyDropDownClick)
    {

       //Use CountryListArray

    }
    else{

      //Use StateListArray

   }

   .....
}
```

May this will give some idea and modify according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the UITableView sections so your countries list can be your sections and your states could be your rows when the section(Countries) list will be closed the rows in that section could be 0, and when tapped and opened you can populate the actual list of rows.

```
@interface States : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end

@interface Countries : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<States *> *states;

@end


@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource>

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray<Countries *> *countries;

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return self.countries.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.countries objectAtIndex:section].states.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
// return your configured cell here
}


@end
```

In the above code i have created two classes one for countries and other for states to map the table correctly hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
UIButton *btnCountry;
UIButton *btnState;
NSMutableArray *tempArray;
NSMutableArray *countryArray;
NSMutableArray *stateArray;
IBOutlet UITableView *tempTable;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *btnCountry;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *btnState;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *countryArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *stateArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *tempArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tempTable;

- (IBAction) showState:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) showCountry:(id)sender;
```

**Here .m Code**

```
@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize btnState,btnCountry, stateArray,countryArray,tempArray;
@synthesize tempTable;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

tempTable.hidden = YES;

countryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"India",@"Pakistan",@"USA",nil];
stateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Gujarat",@"Maharashtra", @"Karnataka",nil];
tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

- (IBAction) showCountry:(id)sender
{
btnCountry = (UIButton *)sender;
tempArray = countryArray;
[tempTable reloadData];
if([btnCountry isSelected])
{
    tempTable.hidden = YES;
    btnCountry.selected = NO;
}
else
{
    tempTable.hidden = NO;
    btnCountry.selected = YES;
}
}


- (IBAction) showState:(id)sender
{
btnState = (UIButton *)sender;
tempArray = stateArray;
[tempTable reloadData];

if([btnState isSelected])
{
    tempTable.hidden = YES;
    btnState.selected = NO;
}
else
{
    tempTable.hidden = NO;
    btnState.selected = YES;
}
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      {

return [tempArray count];
 }


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}


@end
```

Comment: sir, I tried your way but when i am click on countryDropDown Button its not showing the populated data the scroll down list is coming but blank similarly with state button case.I am sharing the link of my page.https://gist.github.com/goel232/0bfecbbcd09e28c0b674873a984cbb52

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabbar for your solution,

Change tab and display content on same table.

For that visit,

[Tab bar display data in same table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244711/ios-tab-bar-controller-containing-same-table-views-inside-all-tabs-but-different)

Hope this will help you.